# Why does the cosmosdb emulator throw this error and how to solve it?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I have been working for a couple days now on trying to get the cosmosdb emulator working. I have a macbook pro and am running windows in virtual box. I have installed the cosmosdb emulator on this virtual machine. I have used [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21) to help with the setup. If I dont get this sorted out soon my team will switch to mongodb/mongodb atlas. I have the emulator running in windows. I am trying to create a new database for my application running in OSX. I click on the explorer tab at the URL:

> https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html

I then click

> new container

I fill out the form to create a new database. When I click ok. I get an error:

```
{   "code": 500,   "body": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Service is currently unavailable, please retry after a while. If this problem persists please contact support.\r\nActivityId: 3653c44c-0a9e-4068-b48f-1651c31eb7b8, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"   },   "headers": {
    "content-location": "https://localhost:8081/dbs/drafts",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "date": "Mon, 12 Oct 2020 17:08:30 GMT",
    "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
    "x-firefox-spdy": "h2",
    "x-ms-activity-id": "3653c44c-0a9e-4068-b48f-1651c31eb7b8",
    "x-ms-gatewayversion": "version=2.11.0",
    "x-ms-throttle-retry-count": 0,
    "x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms": 0   },   "activityId": "3653c44c-0a9e-4068-b48f-1651c31eb7b8" }
```

Why is this happening? How can I create a database in the local cosmosdb emulator for use with the SQL API so that I can interact with it in the UI as well as from my java application?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator's UI only supports SQL API. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21#download-the-emulator)

Refer to [Troubleshooting the emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-local-emulator#troubleshoot-connectivity-issues) for additional details. There is a passage on your error. If this does not address your issue, refer to the steps in Collect Trace Files and then open a support ticket as outlined in this section.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Brown. I want to use the SQL API for this. I am trying to create the table using the UI and I get the above error. How do I create a table that will use the SQL API without receiving the above error?

Comment: Create a table? You mean a container?

Comment: See the added info on Troubleshooting I appended to my answer. This will either resolve the issue or help provide support engineers with enough data to resolve.

Comment: Thanks I went through those steps. I had to create a ticket with azure because the suggestions for fix did not work for me. Thanks again.